# How to update scope model after operating the filters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update the scope model (`$scope.itemsCount`) after operating the filters. Please have a look at my demo code  which is similar to my original functionality.

**Plnkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/grnCth?p=preview

I have used `$watch` to update the model but it didn't worked for me.

Please suggest a solution.

**Required Functionality:** Scope model should be updated. I'm not looking for expression some thing like to show the count.

```
             (item in items|myFilter:startFiltering).length;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call a function from your scope to get the item count. This function can use apply the same filter and get the length of the filtered array.

Here's an updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Z9lAvogqSAbVNJ6eQ89?p=preview

Comment: Thank you sir. Q. If i have more than one filter `myFilter1:filterParam|myFilter2:filterParam|...`. will your function work?

Comment: If you apply all the filters in your function, yes.